# Comma in the end of list of pairs of some alternatives

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need comma right after the word недопустима in the following text:

> Опять же, всё это не является оценкой того, правильна или
>   неправильна, допустима или **недопустима** та или иная тактика со стороны игрока.

Comment: The sentence's structure is awful. At the very least you must omit "насчёт" and both "ли". I would write it like this: "Однако всё сказанное не является оценкой того, правильна или неправильна, допустима или нет та или иная тактика со стороны игрока".

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put the comma after the list of pairs of alternatives. Commas are only needed to separate such pairs, which is done correctly in your example.

Answer (score 1):

> Опять же, всё это не является оценкой того, правильна или неправильна, допустима или недопустима та или иная тактика со стороны игрока.

Частица "ли" в обоих случаях НЕ нужна.
Слово "насчёт" НЕ нужно.
Запятая после слова "неправильна" нужна, запятая после слова "недопустима" НЕ нужна.